# Prevent Adblock Users from Accessing Website?

Tags: php, javascript, user-controls, adblock

Im one of the Users who use Adblock. And i love it.

That question could be interesting for all of us.
Once i visited a german developer website, 
I just saw a jquery fancybox, on that box there was a Message something like this:
"***You are using Adblock, this site is financed with ads. If you want be able to see the content deactivate Adblock or Remove it.***"

First i thought WOW thats funny. Im sure there is also an hack for this.
Just using another user agent would give you access to the website content or not? ididnt tested but it could be Possible.
In Future most Website Owners will prevent Users seeing the content of the site who uses Adblock.

**How could we implement an Script like the above? nomatter which language we use javascript,php,asp,jsp** and how could we **hack** it? with hack i mean seeing the content without deactivating the Adblock.

Comment: I believe that they user's experience is their own. Morally I'm sure you're right but in the meantime I hope that by not answering maybe there will be one less site that tries to do something like this.

Comment: sure i will never use something for my own site but we should also know how we could visit that site without removing the adblock,

Comment: Personally, I figure adblock represents a small minority of users -- users who wouldn't click my ads anyway (and as a result, showing them ads would only lower my clickthrough rate).  They tend to be technically savvy, and may be major content contributors.  By not allowing them to use adblock, I'd probably lose them and the content they create, and I probably won't make any money off them anyway.  That being said, if it's your site, you make the rules.  Just as adblock users have every right to block ads on sites that will let them, site owners have every right to block adblock users.

Comment: re: implementation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock#Detection

Comment: Pesonally, I think Adblock is horrible. People going around using ad-supported sites while thinking they're all clever for blocking the ads, will get what they desrve when those sites close or switch to a subscription model, I guess.

Comment: If a user goes so far as to install a third-party browser extension to block advertisements, then don't you think that user isn't very disposed to clicking your ads?

Comment: If I may:
I work for a site that is completely dependent on sponsorhsips (i.e. ad-revenue). A sponsor pays for a certain amount of impressions per month with a certain click-through percentage. The ad-server does not know whether or not the browser has adBlock installed, so serves it anyway. This means that if could negatively impact our click-through percentage, which in turn will make our sponsor very sad/angry/passive-aggressive/whiny. I simply want to tell our server that it shouldn't even bother with serving the ad because the user won't see it. Mind you, AdBlock usually only blocks serve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.thepcspy.com/read/how_to_block_adblock

Not that you should EVER do it. It's incredibly anti-consumerist and IMO, plainly stupid.

Comment: That page is over two years old and makes odd assumptions on how AdBlock/AdBlock Plus work... iirc AdBlock Plus removes the div from the DOM entirely, so the code presented on that page would just fail with a JavaScript error.

Comment: Ok we should first thing about website owners they can just earn money from advertising. Most site owners earn money from ads, what if no one is seeing ads? can the  click on ads without seeing it? my answer is no.

Comment: @Chuck, because he asked. @R. Bemrose, things are most certainly a bit different, but the concept remains the same. @street: blocking ad block users from visiting your site is akin to cable operators preventing fast forward over commercials in their "DVR" offerings. May be perfectly within their right to do so, but it's pretty stupid, again, IMO.

Comment: @Chris its true and valid in most cases

Answer (score 1):

Just create the content of the site within something which will be blocked by AdBlock, and leave this message on the background.

On the other hand, you could try to get the status of an element using JavaScript, but I'm not sure if this is working.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I will not stop adblock users visiting my site - there is such thing as freedom of the internet. As my site allows you freedom to say and discuss pretty much what you want, then doing such a thing would be hypocritical.

However having said that I would appreciate it if people did visit then they could turn off adblock for my sites pages. I do not have the massive finances to run my site like the big corporations and stores, so it would be a shame if I did have to remove guest posting or make my members pay a small subscription.

Some Internet users assume that small forum and website owners make a fortune in advertizing - this is a myth, in fact we barely even scrape a few bucks towards the hosting costs. Please try to remember this as many of your favorite website will be making a few dollars and taking away that valuable income may see your favorite website disappear.

Comment: Do not include unrelated links in your answers, please. Your answers will get deleted as spam. j0k edited this one out for you; please don't do it again.