# How can I detect if my AdSense ad is blocked?

Tags: javascript, adsense, adblock

If user has some kind of ad blocker installed, ad blocker will of course remove all ads from my website, and it leaves empty spaces where the ads used to be. I would like to use that empty space by putting some other content in it, like links to most important pages of my website, to do that I need to detect if AdSense javascript is loaded.

Methods that I have tried so far:

```
if (!document.getElementById("google_ads_frame1"))
{
}
```

and:

```
if (typeof(window.google_render_ad) == "undefined")
{
}
```

Both of those seem to fail in certain situation, for example if browser downloads AdSense javascript files a bit slower, it will execute above mentioned code before AdSense code is loaded and I end up hiding ads for users that don't even have ads blocked.

Do you have any suggestions on how could I make sure that my code is run after AdSense? Or some other way of detecting that AdSense scripts are not loaded?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this code on the `window.onload` event. `window.onload` event is fired when the page has completed loading.

```
window.onload = function() {
  // your checks
}
```

If you're using jQuery, use

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // your checks
});
```

Comment: Your jQuery example is shorthand for `$(document).ready()`, which will fire before `window.onload`.  You can use jQuery to attach `window.onload` handlers via `$(window).load(fn)`.

Comment: @Dave Ward, oh yes, fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Yup that works, now I feel stupid for not trying that before asking the question :)

Answer (score 9):

If using the new AdSense code, you can do an easy check, without resorting to content or css checks.

Place your ads as normal in your markup:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block;"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-######"
   data-ad-slot="#######"
   data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

Then you call the adsense code at the **bottom** of your page (note do not use the `"async"` flag when calling the `adsbygoogle.js` script):

```
<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Then add this little snippet of code below that:

```
<script>
if (!adsbygoogle.loaded) {
   // do something to alert the user
}
</script>
```

AdSense always creates/sets the flag `adsbygoogle.loaded` to `true` when the ads are loaded. You could place the check in a setTimeout function to delay the check by a few seconds.

Comment: this should be the upvoted answer. Kudos for mentioning setTimeout. Even better is to put the setTimeout insider a `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: What happens if you have more than one adsense ad?

Comment: This doesn't check for the ads are rendered, but checks if the google adsense code is blocked

Comment: This doesn’t work when Adblock isn’t installed. Shows like it is blocked...

Answer (score 4):

This ultra-lightweight method seems to be infallible and is agnostic to all ad networks.

Place a file call **ads.js** in your root folder and add this line inside it:

```
var can_run_ads = true;
```

Adblock won't allow a file named **ads.js** to be loaded. So, just place this code before `</body>`

```
<script src="/ads.js"></script>
<script>
if(window.can_run_ads === undefined) {
    alert('Please Disable Adblock, ****** ******!');
}
</script>';
```

I strongly recommend to redirect the user to a page that has instructions on how to remove **Adblock**.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use FuckAdBlock to detect if AdBlock is activated. If this is the case, you are free to add as many html in your page you want.

See the documentation for examples: https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock

Answer (score 0):

Detect data-ad-status="unfilled" parameter in ins.adsbygoogle to know if the adslot is empty.

Answer (score -4):

After some more tests I realized that issue was not about timing as I previously thought. Problem was that AdSense started to use some new code, this code doesn't have "google_render_ad" function and it doesn't create iframe with ID "google_ads_frame1" (new ID is "aswift_0").
Considering that AdSense now uses at least two different IDs for iframes I made new detection code that checks just for presence of iframe element regardless of its ID:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length === 0)
{
    // ad is blocked
}
```

Comment: Please note that if you are using FB Like, Gplus +1 or similar, you will have many iframes on the page.