# Checking if adsbygoogle is loaded in Firefox Private Window

Tags: javascript, firefox, adblock

I've used this before https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321408/1780386
but now it doesn't work.

I see in F12 -> Network that adsbygoogle.js has status "Blocked". But adsbygoogle.loaded is TRUE.

Comment: Maybe the Google ads script has been replaced by [SmartBlock](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2021/03/23/introducing-smartblock/)?

Comment: Maybe this explains the situation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1713726