# Detect AdBlock _before_ displaying an ad?

Tags: javascript, ads, detect, adblock

A few friends and I were thinking about starting up our own ad company. While thinking about the various ways to display the ads, I realized we needed a way deal with adbloack...

I've been searching on this site, but I can't seem to find an answer to my needs: All off the AdBlock detection stuff is for website owners who are unaffected by detecting adblock after the ads are done "loading".

I need to know if there is a way to detect if a user is using adblock BEFORE we use server resources to send out an image+data to the website so that no resources are wasted.

This would be helpful not just for me, but for other people thinking about starting an ad company or website owners who wish to forgo the entire ad-loading part of their site for users running adblock.

Thanks in advance to any answers, even if they aren't what I want to hear :)

Comment: Maybe something like this might be what you're looking for.


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're evil :-)

if adblock blocks parts of website, it wont even send request to download gif. So no resources are wasted.

Comment: If this is true, that would take out a nice chunk of complexity.
And I'm not evil, the whole reason we want to make this ad company is to reduce the number of crap ads on the web :P