# Disable chrome extensions for visitors of a certain web-site?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chrome extensions can interfere with how a site is rendered and/or its behavior. This introduces unnecessary states and potential sources of errors.

So: Is there a way to disable all Chrome extensions for visitors of a certain website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think such API exists (we are taking about webiste scripts, right?) However you could determine if specific extension installed and update your code accordingly. Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed) how to do this.

Even better and [actual topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180598/ad-blocker-detection-aka-adblock-plus) if you are fighting with adblock plus ;)

Comment: I was hoping the reply would be more 'Yes, Google Chrome allows for a way of turning off all extentions by setting the following <meta> tag'. But I'll attack them on a extension by extension basis instead. Thanks.

Comment: Chrome allows user to decide, user may disable extension anytime, or use browser incognito mode without specific extensions. But user cannot control your website. So I think this is correct behavior now.
BTW Chrome does not allow many things to extensions developers as well to prevent such "unauthorized" things

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle so far is to disable Extension sync in that specific browser.

Steps to follow:
https://superuser.com/questions/528014/how-to-disable-chrome-extensions-without-disabling-them-across-multiple-synced-d

.

[image]

[image]