# Adblock blocks animated head of my web as advertising

Tags: html, animated, adblock

I have made an animated my web with Google web designer but Adblock program detects and blocks ads and do not know if there's any way to fix this header.

The code here because it is huge, but if necessary I upload somewhere

Here: http://textuploader.com/a5ii0

My fear is that my website visitors can not see my animated web header.

HTML that contains the header

```
 <div id="header">
    <Iframe  src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/head/1.html" width="900px" height="201px" frameborder="0" wmode="transparent"> </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit my post whit the code

Comment: link your scripts..... wtf is with the whole block in the beginning

Comment: nobody will be able to understand your copy paste blob, either format the code properly or show us the portion of code where it contains your ad

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ad Blocker detection AKA Adblock Plus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180598/ad-blocker-detection-aka-adblock-plus)

Comment: I edit my post, embed the animation in a Iframe.

Comment: The problem is that my head is not an advertisement, does not even hover region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the code so poorly written/formatted/bloated.... Having an animated header/banner is already poor web convention. The reason Adblock blocks your header is because its robust enough to block annoying ads not to mention animated ones. Frankly I don't even want to see your animated web header.

Edit: I can barely understand your english but users should always have the power to choose whether they want your ad to be blocked or not. You should try showing an alternative to the banner. [Alternate Content for AdBlock](http://www.labnol.org/internet/alternate-content-for-adblock/28602/)

However since you're using Google Web Designer, I can already tell you don't understand HTML/CSS/JavaScript as well as a novice web designer. There won't be an easy way for you to do this if you don't understand your code. Before using a drag and drop builder for your websites, you should learn to code raw HTML and CSS because avoiding AdBlock can already be difficult since their tool is so dynamic.

Comment: I know, but it is a web page of a musical artist and animated header like, before I had a flash animation. I've done it again with Google HTML5 web designer.

Comment: No idea what being a musical artist's web page has to do with anything, an Ad is an Ad and most users hate them.