# "document.createElement('script').onError" always executes with local fuckadblock script, but not with identical script on cdnjs.cloudflare.com

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, adblock

**Background**

I have a hook that uses [fuckadblock](https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock). This is the code for the hook and it works correctly. It detects adblock when adblock is on, and does not detect adblock when adblock is not on. It calls a script from a server, but I want to store the script and run fuckadblock locally. I'm using the Gatsby framework.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

/**
 * Detects of addBlock is enabled
 * @param addBlockDetected What to do when addBlock is detected
 */
export default function(addBlockDetected) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof fuckAdBlock !== 'undefined' || typeof FuckAdBlock !== 'undefined') {
      // If this is the case, it means that something tries to usurp are identity
      // So, considering that it is a detection
      addBlockDetected();
    } else {
      // Otherwise, you import the script FuckAdBlock
      var importFAB = document.createElement('script');
      importFAB.onload = function() {
        // If all goes well, we configure FuckAdBlock
        fuckAdBlock.onDetected(addBlockDetected)
        // fuckAdBlock.onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
      };
      importFAB.onerror = function() {
        // If the script does not load (blocked, integrity error, ...)
        // Then a detection is triggered
        addBlockDetected(); 
      };
      importFAB.integrity = 'sha256-xjwKUY/NgkPjZZBOtOxRYtK20GaqTwUCf7WYCJ1z69w=';
      importFAB.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      // importFAB.src = '../js/fuckadblock.js';
      importFAB.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js';
      document.head.appendChild(importFAB);
    }
  }, [])
}
```

---

**Problem**

I've tried copying the script at `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js` saving it to a local file and using `npm install fuckadblock`. I then change `importFAB.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js';` to `importFAB.src = 'path/to/fuckadblock.js';`

When I do this, it looks like this function is always executed

```
      importFAB.onerror = function() {
        // If the script does not load (blocked, integrity error, ...)
        // Then a detection is triggered
        addBlockDetected(); 
      };
```

This means that it detects that adblock is on regardless of whether adblock is turned on or turned off.

---

I want to store the script locally, and only have adblock detected if adblock is actually enabled.

---

**Update**

I tried updating my script to include importing the npm module but this didn't work

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

/**
 * Detects of jellyBlock is enabled
 * @param adBlockDetected What to do when jellyBlock is detected
 */
export default function(adBlockDetected) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof fuckAdBlock !== 'undefined' || typeof FuckAdBlock !== 'undefined') {
      // If this is the case, it means that something tries to usurp are identity
      // So, considering that it is a detection
      adBlockDetected();
    } else {
      // Otherwise, you import the script FuckAdBlock
      (async () => {
        
        var importFAB = document.createElement('script');
        importFAB.onload = function() {
          // If all goes well, we configure FuckAdBlock
          fuckAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected)
          // fuckAdBlock.onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
        };
        importFAB.onerror = function() {
          // If the script does not load (blocked, integrity error, ...)
          // Then a detection is triggered
          adBlockDetected(); 
        };
        importFAB.integrity = 'sha256-xjwKUY/NgkPjZZBOtOxRYtK20GaqTwUCf7WYCJ1z69w=';
        importFAB.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        try{
          import("fuckadblock").then((fab) => {
            importFAB.src = fab
          }).catch(
            adBlockDetected()  
          ) //'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js';
        }catch{
          adBlockDetected()
        }
  //      importFAB.src = await import("fuckadblock")//'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js';
        document.head.appendChild(importFAB);
          
      })

    }
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using [the static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/#when-to-use-the-static-folder) and then replacing `.src = 'https://cdnjs...` with `.src = './fab.js'` and downloading `fuckadblock.min.js` to `static/fab.js`.  It'll be easier since fab depends on side-effects to do its work.  You can make import work, but it's more involved; you'll probably have to use a `window.fuckAdBlock = false` variable and do manual instantiation.

Comment: I don't use gatsby myself, so I can't really create a working demo for you.  Although I don't see any reason the above comment shouldn't work.  Gatsby uses webpack with the static folder configured for public assets, so presumably it should work, but I can't test it for myself until I set up a gatsby project to see for myself.  I'll do it later and post a demo for you if you still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely that the script location is wrong or not being served.

One way to rectify would be to `import("fuckadblock")` using `npm i fuckadblock`:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'

/**
 * Detects of adBlock is enabled
 * @param adBlockDetected What to do when adBlock is detected
 */
let detected = false;
export default function(adBlockDetected) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if(detected) {
      adBlockDetected();
      return;
    }
    if((typeof fuckAdBlock !== 'undefined' || typeof FuckAdBlock !== 'undefined')) {
      // If this is the case, it means that something tries to usurp are identity
      // So, considering that it is a detection
      adBlockDetected();
    } else {
      (async () => {
        try {
          const fadblock = await import("fuckadblock");
          if(typeof fuckAdBlock === 'undefined' || typeof FuckAdBlock === 'undefined')
            adBlockDetected()
          else
            fuckAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected);
        } catch {
          adBlockDetected();
        }
      })();
    }
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Adblock is never detected using this solution even when adblock is on.

Comment: @Sam, I updated the answer for when ad block may have not broken the request but sent an empty file (also added logging to see what is going on) (also fixed an autocorrect typo)

Comment: @EliasSchablowski have you tested this code with a real deployment?  this will definitely not work as is, unless Sam has his bundler set up to do the lazy load style import the way this code is intended to work

Comment: @EliasSchablowski Yes I tested it and this new solution looks like it produces the same problem; however, I've noticed that if I change the variable name `adBlockDetected` to something else (say `somethingAdBlockDetected`), save this file, and allow hot reload to reload the page, then adBlock will always be detected regardless of whether I have an ad blocker on or off

Comment: @Sam although you might want to set it up to work like this, since it's cleaner and safer to have it inserted properly as part of your build pipeline, downloading from the CDN and appending the script tag at runtime should work, (Assuming that the useEffect is procing correctly and the fab js file is accessible at the relative location it is trying to access).  Did you check the network tab in the developer console to make sure it is actually requesting the fab js file, and using a path that actually exists?

Comment: @user120242 I didn't check the console. The reason I want to set this up locally is so that requesting the script doesn't have a large effect on PageSpeed Insights

Comment: You don't need to use the lazy import then.  Just import it directly for the side effects.  Since it will be compiled with your main script, if they block fab they will also block your main web app, thus breaking your page, forcing them to disable adblock to access your web app.

Comment: @user120242, Lazy Loading might affect the detection due to the whole site being potentially blocked (e.g. no renders)

Comment: @user120242 Could you clarify what to do exactly?

Comment: @Sam, @user120242 is saying to `include "fuckadblock";` at the top of the file, thus if it gets blocked your whole bundle goes down with it - Thus forcing disabling to access rudimentary parts of the application

Comment: Right.  And as @EliasSchablowski explained it might not be what you want, since the whole page might stop working since it would block the entire thing if the patterns detect fab embedding in your bundle (I haven't seen any patterns that do).  It should improve PageSpeed results though (everything is bundled together so it's only one request) and make it (very slightly) harder to do anti-anti-adblock.  Regardless, you should check the dev console to see if it is requesting the fab js file, and the right one, in its current form.

Comment: @EliasSchablowski I updated my question to show how I'm using my `fuckadblock` hook, it's in a collapsed snippet. @user120242 What exactly does the the thing in dev console look like? Not completely sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user120242 I have this in my console with my previous solution `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js.` (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: If you're open to Elias's proposed solution, which I'd also recommend you use, disable automatic instantiation and create a new instance manually like shown here: https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock#instance   If it were me, I'd probably just import it at the top and disable automatic instantiation.

Comment: @user120242 How do I disable automatic installation

Comment: You'll want to set `var fuckAdBlock = false;` before you load the fab script.  And then use `new FuckAdBlock` to generate the instance manually.  Note: this will also work with blockadblock

Comment: @user120242 Sorry you're going to have to be really really specific. Where exactly do I place `fuckAdBlock = new FuckAdBlock;` I tried placing this before I call my script, meaning before the line ` adBlockDetect(adBlockDetected)` and also placed `import {FuckAdBlock} from 'fuckadblock'` at the top, but I get `TypeError: fuckadblock__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.FuckAdBlock is not a constructor`

Comment: @user120242 if I place `fuckAdBlock = new FuckAdBlock()`; right after the line `const fadblock = await import("fuckadblock");`, change it to `fuckAdBlock = new FuckAdBlock({
            checkOnLoad: true,
            resetOnEnd: true
          });` and then wait for hot reload then adblock is detected, but only on hot reload. This happens regardless of whether adBlock is on or off

Comment: @EliasSchablowski Could you update your solution to incorporate what were talking about here? I'm kinda confused