# Firefox not displaying images, assigns gibberish class name to element

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I'll keep this brief for now… I have no idea what this problem could have to do with, so I'll withhold any actual code until someone points me in a direction.

I have a website. This website has some images. All but two of these images display fine in any browser. Two of these images display fine in every browser EXCEPT Firefox. My only lead is this: looking at the two elements in Firefox's "tools", I notice that both elements have been assigned the class "wmwfsqbhwdmaytbjhpmp". Same gibberish for each element. As you can probably tell, I didn't put that there. Seems likely to be related. Maybe it isn't though.

So… do you need my css? My HTML? Could this be a browser issue? I'm a relative beginner to all this, so please bear with me, and please point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the html…

```
<header>
<div id="logo">
    <img src="images/main/logoText.png" alt="logoText">
</div>
<div id="bannerAd">
    <img src="images/main/topAd.jpg" alt="bannerAdTemp">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

To repeat: logoText.png displays fine in any browser, topAd.jpg displays fine in any browser except Firefox. topAd.jpg is the one with the gibberish class applied. Nowhere do I apply classes to it with jquery or anything like it.

---

SOLUTION: Seems to be AdBlock's fault. Further reading: [How to detect Adblock on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website)

Comment: It sounds nigh-on impossible to reproduce :/ so a link to the site is probably best

Comment: I dont actually see any images on that page?

Comment: Yes, the actual guts of the website are (very poorly) password-protected while it's in development. Password: "nope"

Comment: Working fine for me, can you give your version of Firefox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's AdBlock plugin fault.

Comment: That's kind of hilarious since these aren't even ads, just ad stand-ins. Anyway, I interpret this to mean that those Firefox users without AdBlock would see these images, and those with it (like myself) would not. Is there anything you would suggest I do about this?

Comment: That AdBlock filter is based on IDs of elements, so you should rename them. Or just accept it, it's AdBlock's job to block ads after all :)

Comment: Just don't use "banner" or "Ad" anywhere in their ids and I am guessing that they will display. I am not sure why the logo would be blocked though.