# Navigator.plugins does not display all plugins

Tags: javascript, php, html, plugins, browser

I was working on detection of adblock plugin on a web browser and i noticed that

```
navigator.plugins
```

returns an array of `PluginArray` object with a list of plugins installed.

```
Java Applet Plug-in
Shockwave Flash
Picasa
QuickTime Plug-in
```

But unexpectedly it does not return all plugins, plugins such as "**User Agent Switcher**" and "**Adblock**" were not listed (contrary to what is stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.plugins).

Why does it not display all plugins (am i missing something) or how do i display all plugins?

Comment: They are not plugins, they are extensions.

Comment: But shouldnt the function then have been `navigator.extensions` ?

Comment: There's no such thing as navigator.extensions

Answer (score 3):

The browsers don't return an array of plugins anymore, except the most common plugins such as Shockwave flash, Java, etc. I presume to avoid browser fingerprinting. You are supposed to check for each plugin that you are interested in specifically like

> `navigator.plugins["Silverlight Plug-In"].name`

[More info here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting)

Answer (score 0):

You can try check how those extensions modifying your page. As example User Agent Switcher for Chrome:

```
if (window.new_nav && window.old_navigator && window.new_nav.userAgent === navigator.userAgent) {
    console.log('user changed navigator.userAgent, real one:', window.old_navigator.userAgent);
}
```

To detect adBlock you can look into this question -> [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website)

Comment: Due to some requirements, i cant detect changes in DOM, so only options i have is to check if the extension is installed.

Comment: I think it is not possible.