# How to check if an adblocker has blocked a javascript file

Tags: javascript, ads, adblock

Adblocker installed in chrome is blocking all the javascript files which has 'Ads' word in its  name.Is there a ways to check if the user is using an adblocker for his browser and alert him to disable adblocker inorder to view the page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect Adblock on my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website)

Comment: no i checked that question before posting this

Answer (score 0):

This is not bullet proof - but upon document ready, you could check for a variable that is defined in the `*ads*.js` file. If it is not defined, the file was not loaded, thus potentially blocked by an ad blocker.

Comment: is there any method to do it with using a global variables because many javascript files contains the word ads