# How do I define the location of an image for this script?

Tags: javascript

I am eager to put this answer given to another question into practice:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20505898/2174961

However, I am not very familiar with JavaScript and I don't know how to complete the code that goes in the body. How do I include the location of the image to be shown when the condition is true?

```
<script>
    if( window.canRunAds === undefined ){
      // adblocker detected, show fallback
    showFallbackImage();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You watch/read a few JS tutorials and stop asking for every part of everything you want. It will be faster.

Comment: Modify what `showFallbackImage()` does, or write your own.

Comment: Lee Allan: I did earnestly try googling for more than 5 minutes, including looking in the tutorial at w3schools.com where I taught myself HTML/CSS back in the day, but I failed to find the answer.

Shomz: How would one modify it?

Comment: Find what it does in the original script... But the solution that James gave you is just as good.

Comment: If you look at the link in the OP, you'll see that there is no such original script to refer to. Apparently the poster assumed people would know what to do, but I for one didn't. I am trying to implement James' solution but still have questions for him as well. It's not easy being a newbie, but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not precisely sure what you are trying to do, but from the question you linked, you want to post an image asking people not to use adblock, right?

If so, perhaps the SIMPLEST way to approach this problem might be to place an image tag in your html, with a specific id, and change the display style of the image to hide or unhide it.

```
<img src="http://path/to/your/image" id="fallbackImage" class="hide" />
```

Using the following css classes, you can alter the display mode of that image

```
#fallbackImage.hide {
    display: none;
}

#fallbackImage.show {
    display: initial;
}
```

In your javascript, you can display this image by changing its css class:

```
function showFallbackImage() {
    document.getElementById("fallbackImage").className = "show";
}
```

Comment: OOPS posted too soon! Let me write my comment out...

Thank you for replying. I am so much a newbie that I'm not sure where to place the second piece of code you wrote. Does it go within the script I posted in the OP and if so where?


"From the question you linked, you want to post an image asking people not to use adblock, right?"
No, actually not, because that would be against Google AdSense policy as they don't want sites calling attention to ads (i.e. soliciting sympathy clicks). (If the OP of the original question is using AdSense, he's playing with fire in terms of risking a ban.)

Comment: I am so much a newbie that I'm not sure where to place the THIRD piece of code you wrote (before it was the second piece, but that was before your answer was edited). Does it go within the script I posted in the OP and if so where?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in that very same script before or after what was already there.  Don't forget to put the css styles in a <style> tag in the <head>.  For future reference, you might be better to ask these kinds of questions in the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/web-developers).  Some responders may be crude, but asking entry-level questions on SO can be received poorly by the community.

Comment: Roger! Thank you for the help and also for the advice. I do understand that entry-level questions can be annoying (and I did in fact sincerely try to google first). Appreciate the help!