# Disable download button when AdBlock is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense, adblock

I have a lot of video clips on my site available for download. Below code achieves that. 
Now I know how to detect if a user has AdBlock installed, these links helped me: 
1
[help1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254284/if-adblock-is-active-show-one-div-if-adblock-is-not-active-show-another)

2
[help2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website)

3
[help3](https://superuser.com/questions/104118/can-a-site-detect-if-i-use-adblock-in-firefox)

With most these solutions a "general" custom message gets shown if AdBlock is detected but there are no more "tougher" actions implemented, so is it also possible that when a user clicks "download" that the "download" output is a message like "You need to enable advertisements to display in order to download video clips" instead of that the user can actually download the file???

**HTML DOWNLOAD :**

```
<div class="box download-box">
     <a class="button" href="">
          <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download
     </a>
</div>
```

**HTACCESS :**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mov|avi|mp4)$" >
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: dont. just dont.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20505898/20126

Comment: If you went with the `ads.js` solution (from help2), just add the code that adds the button to your `ads.js` file (rather than putting it directly in your HTML). If `ads.js` is blocked, then no download button. Of course, this won't stop somebody who is sufficiently determined and technically competent.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

> Yes you can.

**Long Answer:**

For my case I usually send information to the server on page load contain if there is an ad blocker enabled on the client side and therefore I prevent the media from being sent to the browser.

**How to detect:**

I made a small script that can detect that you can find more info on Github [detect-adblocker](https://github.com/Fortiapp/detect-adblocker).

using it is very simple. you only need to add the script at the top of your head tag like:

```
<head>
<!--adBlocker detection code - START-->
    <script src="//adblocker.fortiapp.com/ads.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function (i, o, g, r) {
            i[o] = (typeof i[o] == typeof undefined) ? g : r
        })(window, 'adblocker', true, false);
    </script>
    <!--adBlocker detection code - END-->

    // some other scripts if any
</head>
```

then later in your main app do:

```
if(adblocker){
    // send information to the server that ad blocker is active and
    // therefore prevent whatever you want from being sent to the user
}
```