# Detecting Ghostery

Tags: javascript, adblock

I need of a simple script for detecting Ghostery, like this of the user **timing** that works well with Adblock on Chrome: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website`

Maybe I can run an ajax request on a URL blocked by an adblocker. If it succeeds, there's no adblocker, if it fails, there's an adblocker?

Comment: adblock programs are very complex, and employ a large number of different methods to ensure that they can continue to operate and not be blocked themselves.  It would be a near impossible task to write one answer here that could possibly cover all possible methods for detecting them.  This is just plain too broad of a request, besides being essentially a duplicate of the question you linked;  hiding the link in a code block doesn't make it suddenly valid...

Comment: The simple method in the question linked works very well on famous Adblock on Chrome. Very efficient. But not with Ghostery. I need for try a method for detected Ghostery if the link of my popup not is loaded.

Comment: ok, so then what are you asking here?  how to make something that works with a bunch of other lesser known adblock programs?  Again, your question is too broad.

Comment: A good method for detected only the program Ghostery.