# Check if request was blocked by user with javascript

Tags: javascript, request, adobe-analytics, adblock

I'm coding a function to detect if users are using **adblockers**. When I detect it I send it to **Site Catalyst (Omniture)**.

The problem is: Some adblockers use a black list to block requests and my company catalyst url it's in one of these lists. 
When I look in the devtools they block the requests and show a ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT.
There's a way to check if a request was blocked by client using javascript?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask.

Comment: Maybe you can perform your request with ajax ?

Comment: Detecting ad blocker is easy check this answer it might be helpful [How to detect ad blocking and show a message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36530565/5751341)

Answer (score 0):

Detecting ad blocker is easy check this answer it might be helpful [How to detect ad blocking and show a message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36530565/5751341)

You can check this out it might help
[detect-adblocker](https://github.com/Fortiapp/detect-adblocker)

Its an implementation of [timing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20505898/5751)

Add this before any script in the head tag:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta/>

    <!--adBlocker detection code - START-->
    <script src="//adblocker.fortiapp.com/ads.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function (i, o, g, r) {
            i[o] = (typeof i[o] == typeof undefined) ? g : r
        })(window, 'adblocker', true, false);
    </script>
    <!--adBlocker detection code - END-->

    // Other scripts

</head>
```

Then later use it:

```
if (adblocker) {
    // the add blocker is enabled
}else{
    // ad blocker is not enabled
}
```