# Adblock Addon Name detection

Tags: javascript, adblock

Is there a way to detect which Adblock Addon a User is using?
E.g. "Adblock Plus", "uBlock", "Ghostery".
I've seen there are quite a few Scripts to detect whether AdBlock is on or off, but so far I didn't find any that tells the Addon used.

Comment: Quick google search for: how to detect adblocker resulted in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website). I don't know about specific blockers though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to detect specific AdBlock plugin.

The only way i could think of, is take their `blacklists`, find difference between each other and then try to simulate specific `block` which is unique in their `blacklist` to distinguish between them.

> when you open a page, adblocker looks at what (mostly JavaScript files) and domains are on its blacklist. Every time your browser will try to load one of these scripts or from one of the listed domains, the blocker will stop your browser from loading that and as a result, the ads will not be loaded and also not displayed.