# Using JS, how can I detect adblockers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adblock

With some simple javascript, how can I detect if the client user is using an Adblocker?

Comment: While [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged on SO, there are already [several similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+ad+blockers+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com). You might want to add your answer there, than creating a new duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963456/8009872

Answer (score 5):

Adblockers detect scripts called `ads.js` or scripts with similar names and then block them so that they don't run. They also detect `id`'s and `classes` that have suspicious names and simply remove them from the `DOM`. So here is one simple trick (explanation below) that can help you detect if your user is using an adblocker or not:

```html
<div id="randomDiv">
  <div class="adBanner">
  </div>
</div>
```

This HTML simply places a random `div` on your page with only one child, an empty `div` that has a `class` of `adBanner`. Now an adblocker would think of the child `div` as an advertisement, and it would remove it.

Using CSS, we can give the `.adBanner` `class` a fixed height and a fixed width, so that it renders something on the screen.

```css
.adBanner {
  height: 2px;
  width: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This CSS simply gives our fake "adBanner" element a fixed width and height that we can check for later, and hides it from the user.

Now using jQuery, we can check for the height or the width of the element. We do this because if the adblocker were to remove this element from the `DOM`, then the height would not exist.

```
if ($("#randomDiv").height() > 1) {
  console.log("No Adblocker!!");
}
else {
  console.log("An adblocker was detected!!");
}
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but this is just one of the ways.

Hope this helps!!!