# Javascript - detect ad blocker detector

Tags: javascript

**Is there any way to detect when an ad-blocker detector is running on a website?** I want to implement a javascript solution to avoid displaying the warning that an user will see if have an ad-blocker active on it's browser.

NB: I don't want to know if an adblocker is running, someone linked a question into the comments but it's not what I'm looking for!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Adblock on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website)

Comment: @hgb123 no, that question is relative to how to detect if an adblocker is running, I need to detect if an adblocker detector is running on a website!