# How to detect net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT status of http requests in javascript (browser)

Tags: javascript, http, browser, error-handling

I couldn't find a way to handle this error status. Are there any fields inside XMLHttpRequest, Fetch, or AxiosError to get this status?

Comment: Try this one. It worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963456/12811479